# Fabricjs: Show preview of the banner

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs 1.5 and I am stuck on 1 thing. I want to show the preview of the canvas to the user on click of button and I can not come up with a proper solution. Some things that crossed my mind are:

- Save the current canvas state and then render it on the other canvas
- Create a temporary image save function and then show this image

But I want to know if there is any specific function in the fabricjs that can help me achieve this. I did some R&D and could not find anything and hence I have not tried anything.

Comment: update to newer version, 1.5 is too old. you can use `canvas,toDataURL()` to get a image of canvas.

Comment: So using image is the best option.

Comment: yes, Use `toDataURL()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get the image of canvas, and set it to image source.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({radius:100,fill:'red'}))
function setPreview(){
 document.getElementById('img').src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="setPreview()">Preview</button><br>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<br>
<img id='img'/>
```